# Файлы по папкам в зависимости от их названия

Tags: python, файлы, shutil

Я совсем начинающий программист, и поэтому даже самые простые задачи у меня вызывают кучу вопросов. 
Поэтому прошу мне помочь:(

Мне нужен небольшой скрипт на python который будет расскидывать "отчеты" с незамысловатыми названиями(Forma_T1_1-140100013467-17.09.2018-11_52_50.xls) из папки "TEST1/Reports/" в папки "TEST1/ОтчетыЖ/НМУПТТ", "TEST1/ОтчетыЖ/ЧТУ", ... "TEST1/ОтчетыЖ/n"; где в названии файла после "Forma_T1_1-" идет четырехзначный указатель.

Как бы объяснить что бы самого себя не запутать. Допустим что эти 4 числа = 1401(как в приведенном в пример файле) тогда нужно закинуть этот файл в папку "TEST1/ОтчетыЖ/НМУПТТ", а если бы было 1023 - то в папку "TEST1/ОтчетыЖ/ЧТУ".

Вот это мое "чудо" мысли:

(пока оно только инициирует файлы, а функцию переноса я закомментировал потому что она временно бесполезна)

```
import os
import shutil
#C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\TEST1\
#C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\TEST1\ОтчетыЖ\НМУПТТ
#C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\TEST1\ОтчетыЖ\ЧТУ
count = 0
main_folder = os.listdir('../TEST1')#файлы в папке
folder2 = os.listdir(main_folder[1])#файлы в 2-ой папки
folder3 = os.listdir(main_folder[2])#файлы в 3-ей папки
files_list = len(os.listdir(main_folder[1]))


def check():
    files_dir = os.path.abspath(folder2[count])
    print('файлов в папке = ', files_list)
    print('файл №', count+1, '=', folder2[count])
    print(files_dir)


def replace():
    files_dir = os.path.abspath(folder2[count])
    file_name = folder3[count]
    if file_name == '210015.txt': 
            shutil.move('folder2/'+file_name, 'folder3/')


while count<files_list:
    check()
    #replace()
    count = count + 1
```

Что бы моя болезнь головного мозга не прогрессировала, пожалуйста подскажите что я делаю не так и как правильнее будет решить эту задачу

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, вам необходимо получить список файлов в папке, по условию определить к какой группе они относятся и перенести в соответствующую папку:

```
file_list = ["...", "..."] # файлы из папки folder_src
for file in file_list:
    if "Forma_T1_1-1401" in file:
        shutil.move(os.path.join("folder_src", file), "folder_dest")
    elif  "Forma_T1_1-0000" in file:
        pass
    else:
        print "unmatched - ", file
```

Answer (score 1):

?

```
import os
import shutil


SRC_DIR = 'C:/...'
MATCHERS = {
  # 'pattern':'dir',
    '1401': 'TEST1/ОтчетыЖ/НМУПТТ',
    '1402': 'TEST1/ОтчетыЖ/ЧТУ'
}


def get_dir_for_file(filename, matchers):
    for pattern, dirname in matchers.items():
        if pattern in filename:
            return dirname
    return None

for filename in os.listdir(SRC_DIR):
    dirname = get_dir_for_file(filename, MATCHERS):
    if dirname is None:
        print('file is not categorized: "{}"'.format(filename))
        continue
    shutil.move(os.path.join(SRC_DIR, filename), dirname)
```

Comment: автор вопроса смотрите сюда. Это мудрый совет)
Для полного феншуя я бы еще после '1402': 'TEST1/ОтчетыЖ/ЧТУ' запятую то бы и поставил...